# How to count specific table column using laravel

Tags: laravel

I have here a laravel query:

```
DB::table('notifications')
    ->leftJoin('domains', 'domains.domain', '=', 'notifications.data->via_domain')
    ->select('notifications.data->via_domain as domain_name')
    ->groupBy('notifications.data->via_domain')
    ->get();
```

This shows domain names that exists between the tables 'notifications' and 'domains'. However, I want to count notifications.notifiable_id field in 'notifications' by:

```
DB::table('notifications')
    ->leftJoin('domains', 'domains.domain', '=', 'notifications.data->via_domain')
    ->selectRaw('count(notifications.notifiable_id), notifications.data->via_domain')
    ->get();
```

However it shows error in SQL syntax.

> (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near

```
via_domain from notifications left join domains on
domains.domain = not at line 1 (SQL: select
count(notifications.notifiable_id), notifications.data->via_domain
from notifications left join domains on domains.domain =
notifications.data->'$."via_domain"')')
```

Thanks for the help, minna-san.

Comment: is `data->via_domain` actually within the table or is this a variable? Can you post the two tables you're joining

Comment: Yes, it is a json field, and it already shows data.

Comment: DOMAINS TABLE
id, int(10) unsigned, NO, PRI, , auto_increment
domain, varchar(255), NO, UNI, , 
description, varchar(255), YES, , , 
country_id, varchar(255), YES, , , 
settings, json, NO, , , 
captor_id, int(11), YES, , , 
account_id, int(11), NO, , , 
owner_email, varchar(255), YES, , , 
owner_phone, varchar(255), YES, , , 
created_at, timestamp, YES, , , 
updated_at, timestamp, YES, , ,

Comment: NOTIFICATIONS TABLE

Comment: 'updated_at', 'timestamp', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'type', 'varchar(255)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'read_at', 'timestamp', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'notifiable_type', 'varchar(255)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'notifiable_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'id', 'char(36)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, ''
'data', 'text', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'created_at', 'timestamp', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got it!

Here's my code:

```
DB::table('notifications')->leftJoin('domains', 'domains.domain', '=', 'notifications.data->via_domain')
                    ->select('notifications.data->via_domain as domainName', DB::raw('COUNT(notifications.notifiable_id) AS leadsCount'))
                    ->groupBy('notifications.data->via_domain')
                    ->get();
```

This results to an array showing the domain name and its leadsCount.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

for example, assume we have data as like below

[image]

```
Couponview::whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date, $end_date])
                ->select('store_id', DB::raw('COUNT(store_id) as store_count'))
                ->groupBy('store_id')
                ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(store_id)'), 'DESC')
                ->take(8)
                ->get();
```

then We got OutPut Like below example image
[image]